# Answer prompt on remote machine via script

Tags: bash, batch-file, ssh, scripting

Following situation:

From a Windows machine, I log into a remote Linux machine via

```
plink -v hostname -l username -pw password
```

Upon logging in, I am greeted with a 'Welcome to AIX Version 5.3!' and asked to choose a login case (at which prompt I need to press '2'), and then to choose a datapool (at which point I need to press '1').

However, I don't want to press anything. I want all of this to happen through a script. How can I automate answering the prompts?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
plink -v hostname -l username -pw password << input.txt
```

where input.txt is:

```
2
1
exit
```

Additionally, all commands which I would like to give to the remote terminal can be included in this input.txt file.